# Correct way to select a specific column from the last row of a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `stock_pick` and trying to set last row of certain column like

```
stock_pick.iloc[-1]["Regime"] = 0
```

This results in the ,

```
/home/prowler/analysis-toolkit/anaconda2/envs/py3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:179: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
```

What is the correct way to pick and assign a value to a specific column in the last row?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [`get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) for position of column and thn is posssible use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
stock_pick.iloc[-1, stock_pick.columns.get_loc("Regime")] = 0
```

Another solution is select by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and select index by position by `[-1]`:

```
stock_pick.loc[stock_pick.index[-1], "Regime"] = 0
```

Comment: What do you think about using `stock_pick['Regime'].iloc[-1] = 0`?

Comment: Thanks.  That worked.

@JohnGalt, I tried that variation but it gave the same warning. :(